# Open GLES and C++ porting to iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have had an android app developed using NDK and all C++ and Open GL ES. How do I port both C++ and Open GL ES to iOS. I know C++ can be used in xcode, but can they both be easy ported to iOS? Is there some single application that will port both or do I need to rewrite lots of it?

Answer (score 3):

Well, given the fact that Android and iOS have a very dissimilar system level API, the OpenGL-ES part is the least of your problems. In fact the OpenGL-ES part will probably the only part that does not require a lot of porting effort at all, as OpenGL-ES is OS idenpendent.

And no, there's no magic "port from OS A to OS B" kind of tool. That's why you try to place as much as possible of the OS dependent code in well contained, easy to replace modules.